# unable to display the homepage of tomcat 6 in eclipse

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm doing a project in JSP. I am using IDE and tomcat 6.0.35.

When I click on my first .jsp and say run on server, it runs fine. But if I only type the URL `localhost:8080` on the server it cannot display the homepage of tomcat.

Also when I start tomcat using the command line, it displays the tomcat home page but cannot display my first .jsp. It is giving an error like: `The requested resource (/project/first.jsp) is not available`.

Comment: Well, why would you want to see the tomcat homepage if you're only working on your project and the files within it?

Comment: no i wanted to run my project on browser only,and it is not running on browser..if i type URL HTTP://localhost:8080 on browser tomcat starts but my project is not running on it

Comment: @user1372442 Then deploy your project to Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the given directory. Try with full permissions.

And by the way I had the same problem when default web directory on Apache was different from workspace directory on IDE.

Comment: i didn't understand,can u plz explain how to solve this prob?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Tomcat used to launch your app won't *have* a default `ROOT` context but will instead use *your* app as the root context (unless you explicitly specify a context).

When you start it from the command line, it's likely your app has not been deployed to *that* Tomcat, has been removed by the IDE, or you're not accessing the JSP page in the correct app context.

Comment: but i m developing my project on my machine only,then why to deploy?

Comment: did u mean that i should make war file of my project and then deploy to tomcat?

Comment: @user1372442 Yes. *Where* Tomcat is isn't relevant; deploying is deploying.

Comment: OK,it is working now,but still i have a question is that why it not working without deploying?why the server unable to find first.jsp page even the given path is also correct.

Comment: @user1372442 Because if you don't deploy it your app isn't there. It's like asking "why can't I eat this sandwich that doesn't exist."